# where can I find a good delphi library?

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

I'm using delphi6, and it lacks the following abilities:

- a library object,
- a list object(looks like TList,TStringList is good enough?)
- a algorithm library(like sort,)
- template library like STL
- dynamic language feature or GC.
- and so on.

how can I find this things?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [Jedi Code Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/). There are good replacements for container classes and sorting algorithms. I don't think there is GC or STL-like library for Delphi 6.

Delphi 6 is behind the times, check [Delphi 2009](http://www.codegear.com/products/delphi/win32) or at least [Turbo Delphi](http://www.turboexplorer.com/delphi)

Comment: Well, there hasn't happened much between 6 and 2008. We're still waiting for 64-bit support

Comment: @Stephan, operator overloading, generics, anonymous methods, refactoring, DUnit integration, code folding, FastMM and fall of Borland are just a few to count :)

Comment: Not interesting, 2009, 2009, ok, worked fine in Delphi 5, not good, worked in D5, finally :)

Answer (score 3):

There is [DeCAL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/decal/), which claims to be similar to the STL. I've never really tested it, however.

Comment: I use DeCAL alot, and like it very much. (A paying customer from when it was named SDL :-) I'm a little bit worried though, since there's no one maintaining it any more. Would probably checked out Bucknall's EZSDL instead.

Comment: DeCAL is very memory-intensive though. Not the one to choose for speed.

Answer (score 2):

There are many third party delphi libraries, components and source code examples on the net.
Just a couple off the top of my head

JEDI http://www.delphi-jedi.org/

and

a Delphi super page http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/

Comment: I believe the Delphi Super Page to be defunct. 

Torry is another candidate: http://www.torry.net/

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to DeCAL (Which is a very good alternative to TList without generics), I will propose [EZSDL by Julian M Bucknall](http://www.boyet.com).

Answer (score 1):

List of main third party components compatible with Delphi 2007 for Win32 and RAD Studio 2007 by Andreano Lanusse at http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/37455

Answer (score -1):

The first three are in the VCL, take a look in the help and the sources. Delphi 6 has no generics, so cannot be used with a template library. And no garbage collection.

If you want to program in Delphi, forget about them. If not, find another language.